# Assigning values to Char* within structure which solution is desirable c++

Tags: c++, c, struct, char

Let me say I have a struct which has full of character pointers. Which is the correct way of initialising the values with a string returning from a function

```
typedef struct details{
char *name;
char *address;
char *nickname;
}details_t

string function() 
{
string name = "random string calculation";
return string;
}
```

case1:

Assigning return values directly. Here I don't understand where the result of string_1.c_str() is stored. Is it in heap as it is of string class?

```
main()
{
details_t details_t1;
details_t1.name = function().c_str();
details_t1.address = function().c_tr();

function_2(details_t1);
}
```

case 2:
Allocating memory in heap

```
main()
{
details_t details_t1;
details_t1.name = (char*)malloc(string_1.size()+1);
strcpy(details_t1.name,string_1.c_str();
....

function_2(details_t1);
}
```

Comment: C has required explicit return types for functions for some time now... but, I wouldn't recommend using `string_1.c_str()` because the C string returned from that function is only guaranteed to exist as long as `string_1` exists.

Comment: Why are you even using C-style `char *` strings in a C++ program ? Just use `std::string` throughout - it will make life a lot easier.

Comment: *"where the result of string_1.c_str() is stored"* - the result is a const char* and it is stored in your struct. The data it points to, however, remains stored in the `std::string`. So when the string goes out of scope the pointer in your struct is pointing at nothing.

Comment: Impossible to give you definitive advice without knowing what you are doing with this struct.

Comment: It does have string's `c_str` which is C++

Comment: @PaulR I need to pass this to a function which is implemented in c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c_str()` is wherever the `string` class currently has the characters - it may be on the heap, it may be using the small string optimisation. It may change if the string gets updated, since C++ strings are not immutable. And it may go out of scope.
Do not use option 1.

Option 2 is far safer. You then have your own copy in the struct.
However, don't forget to free the memory afterwards. 
If you can do C++, use a destructor to tidy up.
ANd then think about copy constructors etc (rule of 3 or 5).

Option 3 may be even better:
Consider just having `std::string`s inside instead. (Rule of 0)

Comment: There are scenarios where option 1 would be the best, e.g. binary interop. We don't know enough about the use of the struct to be that definitive.

Comment: You are right, of course. We also don't know why we have this C struct and if we can change it as both my and Wojtek's answer says.

Comment: @doctorlove: I am using the second option as of now , as I understood that using the .c_str() function is dangerous incase the  string goes out of scope or incase the string position changes or the value gets updated

Answer (score 2):

Both cases are wrong:

1. You store the pointer returned by `c_str`. The lifetime of this pointer is controlled by the string returning it, so it is independent from the `details_t` structure. You are likely to reference memory area no longer valid, because e.g. you will append something to the string, it will reallocate its internal buffer, and your structure will still point to the old buffer.
2. You are allocating memory with `malloc` (nearly always wrong in C++) and assign this memory to members of the structure. This is not technically incorrect, but this is not the way things are done in C++. Assigning structure members to allocated memory with unknown owner is a no.

You should forget about using `char*` in your structure and just use `std::string`.

Comment: The `c_str()` version might be right if the struct was used for interop with some other library, and the function called returned before the strings were modified.

Comment: hi , i am using malloc() because the module i am interfacing is implemented in c , though my implementation is in c++

Comment: @DavidHeffernan :i didnt get this point "the function called returned before the strings were modified"

Comment: The C string returned by `c_str()` is valid only until the string is modified. So if you populate the struct like that, then call the external function immediately, you'll be fine. The huge omission in your question is any explanation as to what you do with the struct. Without that information you won't get very specific advice.

Comment: @vinotheswaran Does the module you are interfacing with free the memory? If not, you do not need to use `malloc` - memory is memory, and C module does not care how it was allocated.

Comment: @WojtekSurowka Why would it do that? That would be the worst designed library ever!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes it would. But sometimes you have no other choice than to use poorly defined library.

Comment: This part of the discussion is rather pointless. Speculating that this is the worst designed library ever seems very unlikely. All sane libraries ask the caller to allocate and deallocate the memory. Assuming anything other than that would be perverse. Judging from the comments that the asker has provided, it is clear that the best course of action is the `c_str()` variant.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What am I missing? `c_str()` returns a `const char *`, but `struct details` uses `char *`. Unless it's `const_cast`'ed it can't even be assigned, and if the struct *does* need modifiable C strings (again, speculating on use), then using `c_str()` is definitely a no go.

Comment: That's simple. Just fix the struct. On the other hand, you appear to be suggesting that the asker should pass `std::string` over this binary interop boundary.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : Ya the interface function will free the memory

Comment: @vinothkumareswaran That sounds completely implausible.